# how can I run setup.exe(vb6 setup toolkit) and install a program using C#

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have some code what launch setup.exe (builded on vb6 setup toolkit)

```
    Process pr = new Process();
    pr.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\to\Setup.exe";
    pr.Start();
```

but what i need to do next for continue install? how i can press "next" for example or put a path to dir?

Comment: I'm not sure, the description says visual basic 6.0 setup toolkit

Answer (score 0):

For a silent installation on Windows systems, use MSI Packages or MSIX.

There a many parameters with for a silent install (-s).
With a MSI package editor, for example ORCA, you can edit MSI Packages and change their paths and default settings.

Take a look at msiexec from the Microsoft documentations:

[DOCU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec)

Comment: i already know about it, but i have installer builded only on vb6 setup toolkit

Comment: Oh, ok, VB6 … Damn, that would be tricky, good luck!

Comment: he-he... i work with it...